# What is the easiest way to make tooltips behave how I want

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip

I don't like the default ToolTip behavior. First, I don't like that, after tooltip is shown for "AutoPopDelay" miliseconds, it disappears and don't appear anymore if you move the mouse over the control again. Second, I don't like that AutoPopDelay is limited to 5000 miliseconds.

I found one way to make tooltip always reappear on mouse move over control, even if it was shown for a time exceeding AutoPopDelay value: I call toolTip.Hide() in MouseLeave handler. This way tooltip will appear again on mouse over.
But I haven't found a simple way to make tooltip stay shown for longer time (longer than maximum 5000 miliseconds). If I call toolTip.Show() in MouseEnter handler, then toolTip is shown in not good position. I like the position in which it shows automatically :)

So, what can you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Show method to control the length of time (it is not limited to 5000ms).

There is a signature for Show that does not require that you set the relative coordinates and there is one that will take the coordinates if you want to fine-tune things.  In your case you will need to pass coordinates (if you don't like what it automatically gives you).  I do not believe there to be an alternative...